# How to accept after at sign must have letter with below regex

Tags: regex

How to accept after at sign must have letter with below regex

http://regex101.com/r/gC2pI3/2

```
/(@+[a-zA-Z]*)/
```

sdsdasd @ewewe@wewe  ewewe@ wewe

make only @ not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want:

```
(@[a-zA-Z]+)
```

The `@` symbol followed by at least one of `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: @user1775888: The `+` here means repeat the previous token at least once